# How to convert constant char pointer to lower case in C?

Tags: c, pointers

I've a function which receives a `const char*` and I want to convert it to lowercase. But I get the error:

`error: array initializer must be an initializer list or string literal`

I tried to copy the string variable to another array so that I could lower case it. But I think I've got something confused.

This is my function:

```
int convert(const char* string)
{
    char temp[] = string;
    temp        = tolower(temp); //error is here
    //do stuff
}
```

I'm struggling to understand what this error means, could someone help in explaining it?

Comment: temp is a string and tolower takes a char/int.

Comment: If you're not going to use a book or other solid learning resource - you'll save a lot of time by reading the documentation for any functions you are having trouble with. `tolower` in this case.

Comment: @MattMcNabb yes, the main confusion is knowing the best way to convert  to int.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`tolower` takes a single character and returns it in lowercase.

Even if it didn't, arrays aren't assignable. Arrays and pointers are not the same thing.

You presumably want to do something like:

```
char *temp = strdup(string); // make a copy

// adjust copy to lowercase
unsigned char *tptr = (unsigned char *)temp;
while(*tptr) {
    *tptr = tolower(*tptr);
    tptr++;
}

// do things

// release copy
free(temp);
```

Make sure you understand the difference between the heap and the stack, and the rules affecting string literals.

Comment: Should be `*tptr = tolower( (unsigned char)*tptr );`

Comment: @MattMcNabb why? `tolower` takes an `int`; type promotion will convert a `char` to an `int`.

Comment: Assuming you mean `char` rather than `char *` in that last comment:  yes, the promotion gives the wrong result.  `tolower` expects an int in the range `0` to `255`, howwever promotion of `char` will give an int in the range `-128` to `127`  (on most systems)

Comment: @MattMcNabb the C99 spec states no such requirement. See 7.4.2.1. "The tolower function converts an uppercase letter to a corresponding lowercase letter. ; If the argument is a character for which isupper is true and there are one or more corresponding characters, as specified by the current locale, for which islower is true, the tolower function returns one of the corresponding characters (always the same one for any given locale); otherwise, the argument is returned unchanged."

Comment: For some reason even with #include<string.h> i can't use `strdup`.

Comment: @Dave it's POSIX rather than ANSI/ISO so sometimes the header it's in isn't completely cross-platform. Give stdlib.h a go, otherwise consult your compiler's documentation.

Comment: @Tommy hmm i have both included but it doesn't like it.

Comment: @chux note to self: don't try to code on a mobile phone. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `tolower`takes `char` or `int`, not string.

but even if you passed `char`, your code wouldn't work, because this error `array initializer must be an initializer list or string literal` ,means you have to initialize it using one of the following methods:

```
char arr[4] = {'h', 'e', 'y','\0'}; // initializer list
char arr[4] = "hey"; // string literal

char arr[] = "hey"; // also a string literal

char arr[4];

arr[0] = 'h';
arr[1] = 'e';
arr[2] = 'y';
arr[4] = '\0';
```

Comment: tolower takes an int argument. Those two arr*s* are not string literals but proper arrays.

Comment: @this array initializer must be an initializer list or string literal is what i said, i didn't get you what are you trying to say.

Comment: Well, arr is an array and "hey" is a string literal, so which one is it? You could clarify this, so readers won't think arr points to a string literal.

Comment: i was saying, array should be initialized with either initializer list or string literal, that is what this is, array `arr` is initialized using a string literal.

Comment: It was a rhetorical question. Your answer is ambiguous.

Comment: I don't know what is ambiguous here..anyways you can post your own answer and help us to understand how to initialize an array.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that, tolower() takes a character and not a string:

```
int tolower ( int c );
```

Also you are trying to copy the string from `string` to `temp[]` variable. There in no overloading of the `=` operator in C to copy the string into `char` array.

Now about your error:

> error: array initializer must be an initializer list or string literal

It says that the array must be initialized via an list of initial individual items or you can directly assign a string literal.

E.g:

> char temp[] = "Hi";
>
> char temp[] = {'H','i','\0'};

Also, check your statement:

```
temp = tolower(temp);
```

Here the return type  of `tolower()` is `int` that you are assigning it to the array `temp` which is improper.

You can use the following snippet using **strlwr()**:

```
int convert(const char* string)
{
    char *temp= malloc(strlen(string)+1);
    strcpy(temp,string);
    strlwr(temp);
    //do your stuff
}
```

Comment: So what is the simplest way to convert in order to lowercase it ?

Comment: @this Can you give details?

Comment: What is malloc doing?

Comment: Note that `strlwr()` is not a C standard function though common in a number of compilers.